# Calculation with jQuery GridViewRow Total not working after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

For normal GridView Row Total calculation, this script works nicely but when I add a new row from GridView footer row, the total amount is not working. This means that after postback this script is not working. How can I solve this?

## ASP.NET GridView Code

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="grdItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridViewStyle"
                GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="There is no data to show."
                Width="100%" OnRowCommand="grdItems_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdItems_RowDataBound">
                <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
                <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="10px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblShowID" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Item") %>'
                                Width="180px" CssClass="text-long" Rows="2" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFItem" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="180px" Rows="2" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtFItem_rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFItem"
                                ErrorMessage="Please enter Item Name!" ValidationGroup="Add" Display="None" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtFItem_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFItem_rfv"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>' Width="30px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCalcQuantity_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcQuantity"
                                ValidationGroup="Remove" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="[0-9]*" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcQuantity_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcQuantity_rev" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcQuantity" runat="server" Width="30px" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtCalcQuantity_rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcQuantity"
                                ErrorMessage="Please enter Quantity!" ValidationGroup="Add" Display="None" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcQuantity_vce1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcQuantity_rfv"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCalcQuantity_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcQuantity"
                                ValidationGroup="Add" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="[0-9]*" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcQuantity_vce2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcQuantity_rev"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UOM">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Unit") %>' Width="50px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server" Width="50px" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cur">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCurrency" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCurrency" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price (Budget)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice", "{0:N}") %>'
                                Width="90px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCalcUnitPrice_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcUnitPrice"
                                ValidationGroup="Remove" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="^\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcUnitPrice_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcUnitPrice_rev" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcUnitPrice" runat="server" Width="90px" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtCalcUnitPrice_rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcUnitPrice"
                                ErrorMessage="Please enter Quantity!" ValidationGroup="Add" Display="None" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcUnitPrice_vce1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcUnitPrice_rfv"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCalcUnitPrice_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcUnitPrice"
                                ValidationGroup="Add" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="^\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcUnitPrice_vce2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcUnitPrice_rev"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount (Budget)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Amount", "{0:N}") %>' Width="95px" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAmount" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Amount").ToString()%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Width="95px" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAmount" runat="server" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <span class="red">#</span>Unit Price (Actual)</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcActUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ActUnitPrice", "{0:N}") %>'
                                Width="90px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCalcActUnitPrice_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcActUnitPrice"
                                ValidationGroup="Purchaser" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="^\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcActUnitPrice_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcActUnitPrice_rev"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcActUnitPrice" runat="server" Width="90px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtCalcActUnitPrice_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCalcActUnitPrice"
                                ValidationGroup="Remove" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="^\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtCalcActUnitPrice_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalcActUnitPrice_rev"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <span class="red">#</span>Amount (Actual)</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblActAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActAmount").ToString()%>'
                                Width="95px" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfActAmount" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ActAmount").ToString()%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblActAmount" runat="server" Width="95px" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfActAmount" runat="server" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <span class="red">#</span>Type</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" CssClass="text-small" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" CssClass="text-small" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                        
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <span class="red">#</span>DO No.</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDO" runat="server" Width="90px" Text='<%# Bind("DONo") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFDO" runat="server" Width="90px" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <span class="red">#</span>Date of DO</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDODate" runat="server" Width="90px" Text='<%# Bind("DODate", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>' />
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDODate_ce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDODate"
                                PopupPosition="Right" Animated="true" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtDODate_me" runat="server" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False"
                                CultureName="en-GB" Mask="99-LLL-9999" TargetControlID="txtDODate" UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtDODate_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDODate"
                                Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid date format dd-MMM-yyyy" ValidationGroup="None"
                                ValidationExpression="^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(19|20)\d\d$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtDODate_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDODate_rev"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDODate" runat="server" Width="90px" />
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDODate_ce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDODate"
                                PopupPosition="Right" Animated="true" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtDODate_me" runat="server" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False"
                                CultureName="en-GB" Mask="99-LLL-9999" TargetControlID="txtDODate" UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtDODate_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDODate"
                                Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid date format dd-MMM-yyyy" ValidationGroup="None"
                                ValidationExpression="^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(19|20)\d\d$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtDODate_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDODate_rev"
                                CssClass="customCalloutStyle" WarningIconImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_111.png"
                                CloseImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Img/001_051.png" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        FooterStyle-CssClass="action" ItemStyle-CssClass="action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CssClass="delete"
                                Text="Del" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Add" CommandName="Insert"
                                CssClass="add" Text="Add" />
                            <%--OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this?');"--%></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Supplier_DS" runat="server" SelectCommand="Select '' as ID, '' as Name 
                Union Select ID, Name From tbl_Supplier Group By ID, Name Order By Name" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RFP_CS %>" />
            <table style="float: right; width: 100%; text-align: right;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="color: Red; text-align: right; width: 200px">
                            <span class="red">#</span>Discount (Actual)
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 110px">
                            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscount" runat="server" CssClass="text-medium" Style="text-align: right;
                                color: Red" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtDiscount_TextChanged" Width="105px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtDiscount_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDiscount"
                                ValidationGroup="submit" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtDiscount_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDiscount_rev" />--%>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 310px; text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtActDiscount" runat="server" CssClass="text-medium" Style="text-align: right;
                                color: Red" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtActDiscount_TextChanged" Width="105px" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtActDiscount_rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtActDiscount"
                                ValidationGroup="submit" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid format 99.999!"
                                ValidationExpression="^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$" />
                            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="txtActDiscount_vce" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtActDiscount_rev" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 290px">
                            Total
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 110px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" CssClass="text-medium" Width="110px" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 310px; text-align: left;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblActTotal" runat="server" CssClass="text-medium" Width="110px" Style="text-align: right" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfActTotal" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

## JQuery GridView Calculation

```
// For GridView Calculation
$("[id*=grdItems]input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").live("keyup", function(e) {
    var quantity = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcQuantity]").val();
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcUnitPrice]").val().replace(/,/g, '');
    var actprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcActUnitPrice]").val().replace(/,/g, '');

    var total = parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity);
    var acttotal = parseFloat(actprice) * parseInt(quantity);


    if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblAmount]").text(total.toFixed(2));
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=hfAmount]").val(total);

    if (isNaN(acttotal)) acttotal = 0;
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblActAmount]").text(acttotal.toFixed(2));
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=hfActAmount]").val(acttotal);

    GrossTotal();
    GrossActTotal();
});    

var gross;
function GrossTotal() {
    gross = 0;
    $("[id*=grdItems][id*=hfAmount]").each(function(index, val) {

        var value = parseFloat($(val).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
        if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
        gross = gross + value;
    });
    $("[id*=lblTotal]").text(gross.toFixed(2));

}

var actgross;
function GrossActTotal() {
    actgross = 0;
    $("[id*=grdItems][id*=lblActAmount]").each(function(index, actitem) {

        var value = parseFloat($(actitem).text().replace(/,/g, ''));
        if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
        actgross = actgross + value;
    });

    var discount = parseFloat($("[id*=txtActDiscount]").text());
    if (isNaN(discount)) discount = 0;
    actgross = actgross - discount;

    $("[id*=lblActTotal]").text(actgross.toFixed(2));
    $("[id*=hfActTotal]").val(actgross);

}
```

Comment: do you use updatepanel ?

Comment: yes bro, i used gridview and label_total inside updatepanel

Answer (score 1):

When you use UpdatePanel, after the post back the DOM (struct of html and elements) has change and the javascript that you have setup, need to initialize again. For this reason UpdatePanel offer this javascript functionality.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      

}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
}
```

Now on the EndRequest you need to re-initialize your javascript. Your final javascript will be

```
    function InitCalculus()
    {
    // For GridView Calculation
    $("[id*=grdItems]input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").live("keyup", function(e) {
        var quantity = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcQuantity]").val();
        var price = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcUnitPrice]").val().replace(/,/g, '');
        var actprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcActUnitPrice]").val().replace(/,/g, '');

        var total = parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity);
        var acttotal = parseFloat(actprice) * parseInt(quantity);


        if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
        $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblAmount]").text(total.toFixed(2));
        $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=hfAmount]").val(total);

        if (isNaN(acttotal)) acttotal = 0;
        $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblActAmount]").text(acttotal.toFixed(2));
        $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=hfActAmount]").val(acttotal);

        GrossTotal();
        GrossActTotal();
    }); 
    }

   // you can run this onload page, I just place it here to simulate your code
   InitCalculus();

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      

    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
       InitCalculus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id*=grdItems]').find('input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]').live('keyup', function (e) { 

});

//Or 

$("[id*=grdItems] input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").live("keyup", function(e) { 

});

//Or 

$("[id*=grdItems] > input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").live("keyup", function(e) { 

});
```

//====================================================//

```
$('[id*=grdItems]').find('input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]').on('keyup', function (e) { 

});

//Or 

$("[id*=grdItems] input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").on("keyup", function(e) { 

});

//Or 

$("[id*=grdItems] > input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").on("keyup", function(e) { 

});
```

Comment: I updated my GridView Code in my questions and C# code is just bind only.

Comment: when i key in textbox, the query is okay, postback after insert one row, query is not working.

Comment: what jquery  version u r using? use on -> live try this and see

Comment: I used JQuery 1.7.1 and actually that gridview calculation is working perfectly. The problem is after I added one row in gridview from GridView rowcommand event, I don't know how to call/ calculate my gridview. So I used GridView_RowDataBound. Actually I want to use jquery, that's why
`<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Add" CommandName="Insert" 
                                CssClass="add" Text="Add" />`